# How to avoid unity lens to capture the meta key so I can use EMACS?

Tags: unity, 14.04, emacs

When I use the graphical EMACS and I want for, for example, execute  `M-x`  . as soon as I press the Meta key the unity dash opens and I lose focus from emacs, this is really annoying. how do I avoid unity capturing it?